# Google +1 Version of Sharer Url?

Tags: google-plus

I am adding the Google +1 plugin into my site, however, I wish to also have links that will redirect the user to Google +1 my site.

For example, Facebook and Twitter allow you to share content with `facebook.com/?sharer.php=URL` and `twitter.com/?tweet=message` etc, what is the Google +1 version of this?

Comment: what exactly would you be posting to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look at the g+ button at the left of your question :)

Example : 
https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fq%2f6366204%2f1082031?sgp=1

Answer (score -3):

[http://hehe.freevar.com/googl/share.php?url=url to shortener](http://hehe.freevar.com/googl/share.php?url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366204/google-1-version-of-sharer-url)

[example 1](http://hehe.freevar.com/googl/share.php?url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366204/google-1-version-of-sharer-url)
[example 2 with redirect](http://hehe.freevar.com/googl/share.php?url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366204/google-1-version-of-sharer-url&r=1)

Comment: I have no idea what you just wrote, I don't even think it's in english!